# Trying to resolve an error with discord.py command in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2uE6.png)

the error is scord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author' if anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the structure of ctx object passed in.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Be sure to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always paste your code in code blocks instead of images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by default, the ctx would be the first word that the message author types after invoking the command as it is the first argument passed into the function. So if the author typed "!reg more than one word" into the chat, more would be taken as the value of ctx. You can just typehint and put

```
async def reg(self, ctx: commands.Context, *args):
    "The rest of the code"
```